# React Native bundle loading slowly or not at all

Tags: ios, react-native, sockets, dns, node-webkit

The problem seems to be network-specific, the console log points to two possible errors causing the slowdown:

> nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C150094]
>   DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)

or

> nw_socket_handle_socket_event  Socket SO_ERROR [61:
>   Connection refused]

I tried two network configurations:

1. The development Mac and the iPhone on the same subnet (WiFi) of a larger corporate network - JS bundle loads slowly or not at all
2. Direct connection between the development Mac (WiFi hotspot) and the iPhone - JS bundle loads very fast

`AppDelegate.m`

```
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

`/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh`:

```
# Enables iOS devices to get the IP address of the machine running Metro Bundler
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" = *Debug* && ! "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *simulator ]]; then
  IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
  if [ -z "$IP" ]; then
    IP=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -v ' 127.' | cut -d\   -f2  | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')
  fi

  echo "$IP" > "$DEST/ip.txt"
fi
```

Network interfaces:

```
$ ifconfig | grep 'inet '
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 <- Localhost
inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 0xfffff800 broadcast 10.10.7.255 <- Cable (en0)
inet yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy netmask 0xfffff800 broadcast 10.10.55.255 <- Wireless (en1)
inet 169.254.174.6 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255 <- RN Packager
```

Console log:

```
error   17:09:36.741707+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29701] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.743554+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29702] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.745285+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29703] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.745877+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29704] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.747514+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29705] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.748616+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29714] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.749197+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29715] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.750118+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29716] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.751705+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29717] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.752599+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29718] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:36.753707+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29719] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.257411+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29725] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.258018+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29731] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.258969+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29732] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.259757+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29733] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.261023+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29734] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.261598+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29735] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.263278+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29736] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.264353+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29737] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.265340+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29745] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.265913+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29746] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.266989+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29747] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.267868+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29748] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.269294+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29749] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.270294+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29750] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.271071+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29751] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.271384+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29758] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.271955+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29759] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.273083+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29760] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.273659+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29761] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.274663+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29762] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.275233+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29763] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.275813+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29764] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.276921+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29765] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.278096+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29766] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.278948+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29775] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.280069+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29776] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.281327+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29777] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.282205+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29778] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.282999+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29779] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.283580+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29780] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.284501+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29781] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.286073+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29788] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.286667+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29789] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.287760+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29790] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.288697+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29791] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.289472+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29792] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.290365+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29793] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.291999+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29801] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.293474+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29802] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.294349+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29803] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.295423+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29804] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.297020+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29805] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.297929+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29806] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.299973+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29814] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.300942+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29815] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.301518+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29816] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.303319+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29817] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.304447+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29818] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.374444+0100    MyApp   nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C29819] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
error   17:09:37.374644+0100    MyApp   TCP Conn 0x2817b6a00 Failed : error 0:-65539 [-65539]
error   17:09:37.375264+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.375571+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.375977+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.376354+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.376669+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.376986+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.377598+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.378521+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.379112+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.379523+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.379827+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
```

Later...

```
error   17:09:37.560003+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.580106+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.580409+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.580713+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.581020+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.581325+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.581624+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.581927+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.662981+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.663283+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.663631+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.664028+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.664376+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.664755+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.665090+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.665432+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.665777+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.666107+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.666439+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.743908+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.799060+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29857] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
error   17:09:37.799824+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29858] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
error   17:09:37.800467+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29859] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.801033+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29860] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.801603+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29861] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.802180+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29862] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.802745+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29863] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.803313+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29864] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.804091+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29874] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.804668+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29875] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.805233+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29876] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.805802+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29877] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.806370+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29878] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.806932+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29879] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.807502+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29880] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.808068+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29881] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.808645+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29882] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.809211+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29883] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.809777+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29884] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.810345+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29885] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.901485+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.901839+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.902196+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.902527+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.902852+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.903191+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.903529+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.903848+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.904181+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.904510+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.904864+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.905194+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.905538+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.905893+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.906202+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.906529+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.906866+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.912981+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.918026+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:37.929966+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29902] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
error   17:09:37.930722+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29903] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)
error   17:09:37.931337+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29904] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.931911+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29905] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.932475+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29906] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.933039+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29907] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.933240+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29914] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.933819+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29915] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.934386+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29916] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.934966+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29917] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.935533+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29918] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.936104+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29919] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.936665+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29920] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.937233+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29921] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.937805+0100    MyApp   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C29922] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: NoMemory(-65539)
error   17:09:37.945795+0100    MyApp   nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C29922] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
error   17:09:38.999588+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:38.999922+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:09:38.000298+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
```

Later...

```
error   17:10:30.563154+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:30.563445+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:30.563740+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:30.564030+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:30.564331+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:30.564630+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:30.564924+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:31.898529+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.144762+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_connect [C35257.1:1] connectx(16, [srcif=0, srcaddr=<private>, dstaddr=<private>], SAE_ASSOCID_ANY, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, SAE_CONNID_ANY) failed: [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.144828+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_connect <private> connectx failed (fd 16) [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.144884+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_connect connectx failed [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.153072+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.153362+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.153783+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.155424+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:32.156145+0100    MyApp   nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C35259] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
error   17:10:32.156346+0100    MyApp   TCP Conn 0x2817bd440 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
error   17:10:33.271516+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:33.272726+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:33.278913+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:33.285942+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
```

Later...

```
error   17:10:34.096239+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:34.096532+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:34.096827+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:34.097116+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:34.097414+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:34.097708+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:34.098004+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:35.816966+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:35.817272+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.050535+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.051439+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.051804+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.052109+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.052398+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.052694+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.052989+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.053281+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.053576+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.053900+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.054222+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.054553+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.054884+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.055226+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.055583+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.055923+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.056241+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.056566+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.056895+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.057221+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.057526+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.057820+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.058268+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.058896+0100    MyApp   nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C35675] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
error   17:10:36.059063+0100    MyApp   TCP Conn 0x2818da4c0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
error   17:10:36.167032+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_connect [C35676.1:1] connectx(16, [srcif=0, srcaddr=<private>, dstaddr=<private>], SAE_ASSOCID_ANY, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, SAE_CONNID_ANY) failed: [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.167088+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_connect <private> connectx failed (fd 16) [61: Connection refused]
error   17:10:36.167164+0100    MyApp   nw_socket_connect connectx failed [61: Connection refused]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update with RN** `0.60+`: Custom settings in `react-native-xcode.sh` get overwritten when running `pod install`.

The problem was that my Mac was connected to both WiFi and ethernet at the same time (`en0`, `en8`, and `en9` were all in use). `RCTBundleURLProvider` was taking the `en0` as default one and it was causing some weird redirections.

I guess React Native does not support multiple network interfaces yet, so I ended up modifying `AppDelegate.m` with the correct IP. The problem with this approach is that the IP changes:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://<en8-IP-address>:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios"];
#else
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
#endif
```

A better alternative would be to fix it in the packager itself inside `react-native-xcode.sh`:

```
# Enables iOS devices to get the IP address of the machine running Metro Bundler
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" = *Debug* && ! "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *simulator ]]; then
  IP=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -v ' 127.' | cut -d\   -f2  | grep '169.254.')

  echo "$IP" > "$DEST/ip.txt"
fi
```